# firebase - get all snapshots from list of refrences

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

firestore database in `user` collection:

```
id1: {
    name: 'test',
    friends: [
        users/id2,
        users/id3
    ]
}

id2: {...}
id3: {...}
```

I'm trying to receive the snapshots of all references in `friends` array. (`myRef` si a reference to `users/id1`)

```js
const refFriends = (await getDoc(myRef)).data().friends;
const friendsSnaps = await getDocs(refFriends);
console.log(friendsSnaps);
```

When running, I get this error.

> [Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Expected type 'pc', but it was: an array]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The [`getDocs()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#getdocs) takes a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query) as paramater and not an array of [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference). You can map an array of [`getDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#getdoc) from 'friends' array and use `Promise.all()` to fetch them at once:

```
const refFriends = (await getDoc(myRef)).data().friends;

const friendsSnaps = await Promise.all(refFriends.map((f) => getDoc(f)));
```

Alternatively, you could map array of document IDs and then use `in` operator to fetch the documents in a single query but this works only when you have up to 10 friends.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what if I have 200 friends? Doesn’t 200 querys overwhelm the server?

Comment: @lordcommander a single query would be definitely better but this should not be an issue. You can also paginate the docs. Also take a look at [in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) operator mentioned in my answer so you can query up to 10 docs in a single query.

Comment: The problem is that every user will have around 500 friends, the ‘in’ operator will make that 50 querys. 
That’s 50 query’s for one user only on opening his ‘friends’ page. Isn’t there any other way?

Comment: @lordcommander not with the Client SDK. The NodeJS SDK ([`@google-cloud/firestore`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/firestore)) does support that using `getAll()` method but this SDK meant to be used on server side like in a Cloud function. If you want to fetch all documents in a single query then using a Cloud function is an option.